# camunda - deployment fluent BPMN model API in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

I would like to ask about camunda process with fluent BPMN model API in spring boot. 
What is best practice for setting auto deployment and redeploy (versioning)?

```
@Configuration
public class BpmProcess {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private ProcessEngine processEngine;

    @Bean
    public BpmnModelInstance bpmnModelInstance() {
        BpmnModelInstance modelInstance = Bpmn.createExecutableProcess("esign-store")
                .name("esign store document")
                .startEvent("esign-startEvent")
                .serviceTask("esign-uploadStorage")
                    .name("upload to storage")
                    .camundaAsyncBefore()
                    .camundaDelegateExpression("${uploadStorageDelegate}")
                .serviceTask("esign-uploadCezar")
                    .name("upload to cezar")
                    .camundaAsyncBefore()
                    .camundaDelegateExpression("${uploadCezarDelegate}")
                .endEvent("esign-endEvent")
                    .camundaAsyncBefore()
                    .messageEventDefinition("esign-endEventDefinition")
                .done();

        MessageEventDefinition event = modelInstance.getModelElementById("esign-endEventDefinition");
        event.setCamundaDelegateExpression("${endReplyDelegate}");
        Bpmn.writeModelToStream(System.out, modelInstance);

        return modelInstance;

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void deploy(){
        processEngine.getRepositoryService()
                .createDeployment()
                .addModelInstance("esign-store.bpmn", bpmnModelInstance())
                .name("esign-store-service")
                .deploy();
    }

}
```

I don't know if it is correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PostConstruct is too early, you have to wait until the engine is set up and running. With camunda spring boot, you can listen to the PostDeployEvent and use this a s a hook:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableProcessApplication
 public class MyApp {
   ...
   @EventListener
   public void onStart(PostDeployEvent event) {
       // deploy here
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works fine but I have another problem with it. I am using spring integration to start process from amqp. Problem is that amqp bean gets configured before process is deployed. I don’t know how to set order of configuration class so that amqp bean gets configured after postDeployEvent.

Comment: I was able to resolve order of configuration with controlBus. @Jan thank you